# How do I alter the default node URL rendered in a view?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that shows a list of node titles, where the node title is linked to the node detail page. I want to alter the node URL with a custom one.

How can I alter the node URL?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you set a URL alias when you creating/updating a node this new url will be used for your nodes links. If you didn't set a URL alias for your nodes, clear the caches after set. In my dev site working fine just doing this.

[image: path_alias]

Comment: This way, I have to change every time when i create a node.But i want to add in pathauto as a pattern.                                                                                                         e.g. node url is like /content/article-1 and i want to apply like: myarticles/1 where "1" is nid and "myarticles" is view page path.

Comment: @PareshaU sorry, can you explain better your needs, what do you already done (installed modules, config already set, anything in context of your question)? and what you really need? Your question tells nothing about pathauto, this changes the subject.

Comment: I am done with solution using views page twig file to alter node url with custom url. Thank you very much for your time.